# Do apps need to be started once to receive background data

Tags: notifications, 5.1-lollipop, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-a3

I just recently bought my first Android based phone (Samsung Galaxy A3).

One thing I noticed (or maybe imagined noticing?) is that I appear to only receive notifications (like a new message in WhatsApp or a new email) if that app was previously started (and thereby listed in the "Running Apps" screen).

Is that true? Would that not defeat the purpose of notifications? I tried searching for settings that would imply such a behaviour, but couldn't find any.

- Restrict background data is turned **off**
- WhatsApp/Gmail, etc. all have background data **enabled**
- *Sync* (from the top shortcut menu) is **enabled**
- Accounts/Sync settings for WhatsApp and Google Accounts are **enabled**
- I have a DataUsage warning at 400MB (reached) and a limit at 500MB (not yet reached)
- Network connection is set to LTE/3G/2G (automatic) and I am in 4G currently

Thats about all I could think off / find... Is there more to check?

Comment: Yes and no. Such apps usually start a "service" as soon as the device has its `boot_completed`, so they should be "started" automatically (not the entire app with its GUI etc, but the corresponding service to listen for and show notifications).

Comment: I can see those services, yes. I assumed that would be enough. But e.g. the GMail App only ever synchronizes when I open it, which is annoying to say the least. Did I disable some basic "background sync / pull" service maybe?

Comment: That could be the case indeed. Maybe you [edit] your question and include what you've disabled that sounds at least remotely related? Then we could say more.

Comment: Specific to gmail, you may have disabled sync in Google settings

Comment: I added some more information on what settings I checked / believed to be relevant.